# Is it possible to make the background transparent?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to make the background transparent ? 
I need to see android launcher as background.

```
class MyAppT2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body:Container(
        color: Colors.red.shade200,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child:  Text("asdsa"),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

Now background is black i need to show android device home page

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully and edit your question. There is no why to understand what you meant.

Comment: grammarly auto  correct make this issue

Comment: Please share the code that you have right now. There are a few different ways to configure a background and the answer is dependent on how you built yours.

Comment: updated please check it

Comment: Ehat do you meant by **background transparent** if do like above you will get black screen rather than scaffold color.

Comment: No, you cannot do that.